# How would I get this effect using envelope distort?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Driving myself crazy trying to figure it out. Am a beginner.

[image: http://i63.tinypic.com/ib9ncy.jpg]

Comment: Please edit your question and share what you have tried.

Answer (score 2):

## Envelope Shape

[image]

## Text

The text is distorted after converting it to outlines. I did it editing the envelope content.

[image]

## Result

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for responding, is this done through using Top object as envelope?

Comment: Yes: using top object as envelope

Answer (score 1):

Outline your text, draw 2 line to divide it with Object > Path > Divide objects below:

[image]

Divide two times, Ungroup, remove the top part. I have moved it aside and colored the mid part to green to show it:

[image]

It's a good idea to group the mid part for easy selection. Now it can be distorted. It can be stretched with the direct selection tool by selecting at first the topmost nodes:

[image]

Actually this step wasn't necessary, if there's no horizontal parts.

Then make envelope distort, mesh size = 1 x 1

[image]

Only one division is needed, if you want to save top parts, but the stretching before envelope distortion is a must to avoid thickening the horizontal parts

Be patient, it takes a while to learn how to manage the mesh points and handles. It's easy to think you would have more control with more complex mesh. For ex. in theory no division is needed, if you have enough rows in the mesh. It's true, but in practice the things become easily unmanageable. Use as simple mesh as possible.

Comment: Thank you everyone so much for the help and  advice I will try them out 

Comment: Might I ask what font you have chosen here as well?

Comment: It's Microsoft Sans Serif, but it's made thicker with stroke and stretched vertically. The stroke was outlined and united with the already outlined original text. Why? Because that font happened to be present due my other tinkerings and I saw it can be used for this, only a few clicks more and no font searching needed. BTW I thought nobody cares.